# Differential system in 4 nonlinear equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have some problems in solving the following differential system.
To simplify notation, I write $x$ for $x(t)$ and $x'$ for $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} x(t)$

$$
\begin{cases}
w'=w^{a+1} & \\
x'=x^{b+1}w^{a-b}& \\
y'=y^{c+1}w^{a-c}& \\
z'=z^{d+1}w^{a-d}& \\
\end{cases}
$$

The initial conditions are

$$
\begin{cases}
w(0)=w_0&\\
x(0)=x_0& \\
y(0)=y_0& \\
z(0)=z_0& \\
\end{cases}
$$

#### Progress

Until now I have solved the equation in $w$ directly, getting $w(t)=w_0(1-aw_0^at)^{-1/a}$. But then I am not sure how to continue.

Comment: What is $v$? Is this a constant or is it in fact $w$ you wanted to talk about?

Comment: Yes, v is in reality w. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Until now I have solved the equation in w directly, getting $w(t)=w_0(1-aw_0^at)^{-1/a}$.
But then I am not sure how to continue.

Comment: Now try plugging your $w(t)$ into the other equations and seeing them decouple into separate equations in $x, y, z$ and $t$!

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it: $x(t)=x_0(1-x_0^b(w_0^{-b}-w(t)^{-b}))^{-1/b}$. And similarly for the other equations.

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track to me!   Also, Chinny84 has a nice solution.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
w' = w^{a+1}\\
x^{-b-1}x' = \frac{-1}{b}\left(x^{-b}\right)' = w^{a-b}\\
y^{-c-1}y' = \frac{-1}{c}\left(y^{-c}\right)'  =w^{a-c}\\
z^{-d-1}z' = \frac{-1}{d}\left(z^{-d}\right)' = w^{a-d}
$$
also we can do
$$
w^{-n -1}w' = \frac{-1}{n}\left(w^{-n}\right)' = w^{a-n}
$$
where $n$ can be any of the $b,c$ or $d$. Does this help you.